# Asociar usuario ftp a carpeta /var/www/inventaros

Tags: linux, web, servidor, vsftp

Tengo algunos problemas al crear un usuario ftp y asociarlo a una carpeta en /var/www/inventarios, lo he realizado con /home/usuario, y funciona, pero quiero que este solo se pueda conectar a su proyecto en /www, el problema es que no lo he logrado, al hacerlo por cliente ftp sale "el servidor ha enviado el estado 1 como retorno de comando."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba a quitarle permisos de escritura a `/www`

```
chmod -w /var/www
```

Después dale todos los permisos a `/inventarios`

```
chmod 666 /var/www/inventarios
```

Y vuelve a a intentar conectarte.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias Aritz, me ha funcionado